# Bring the another App in the front when receiving the broadcast

Tags: android

I am sending a broadcast from App A to App B and I am already receiving it in app B. After receiving the broadcast I want to bring the App B to the front. How can I bring the App B to the front after receiving the broadcast from the App A?

```
package com.mysender;  
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final Intent intent=new Intent();
        intent.setAction("com.mysender.Data");
        intent.putExtra("path", "/Download/income_tax_return.pdf");
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES);
        sendBroadcast(intent);

    }
}
```

In the App B I am doing the following in the MainActivity:

```
package com.example.app;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.content.IntentFilter;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

        private WebView mWebView;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            // Receive broad Cast fromn External App
            IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("com.mysender.Data");
            registerReceiver(myReceiver, filter);

        }
        private MyReceiver myReceiver =new MyReceiver(){
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                String path = intent.getStringExtra("path");
                Toast.makeText(context,"Data Received from External App: " + path, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        };

        @Override
        protected void onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy();
            unregisterReceiver(myReceiver);

        }
    }
```